# convert ElasticSearch SearchResponse object to JsonObject

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to convert the elasticsearch search result to Json Object. I havent found any proper way to convert directly.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index).setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();

response->JSON Object.
```

Is there any way to convert an ElasticSearch response to a Json Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can directly convert the SearchResponse to JSONObject.
Below is the handy code.

```
SearchResponse SR = builder.setQuery(QB).addAggregation(AB).get();

JSONObject SRJSON = new JSONObject(SR.toString());
```

Comment: I have using the same but it is saying... constructor JSONObject(String) undefined any Idea.
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch(_index).setSize(0).addAggregation(aggregation).execute().actionGet();

JSONObject SRJSON = new JSONObject(res.toString());

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`SearchResponse.toXContent()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/ed151d829d9e41529b101abec40018c1acab2c83/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchResponse.java#L202-L208) method like this:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index).setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();

XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
response.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.string());
```