# ElasticSearch SearchResponse object with aggregation to JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am going to ask the same question again [Convert SearchResponse to JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190070/convert-elasticsearch-searchresponse-object-to-jsonobject)

Actually I am using the same solution as mentioned in this question. But this solution is not working for me.

Below is my Elastic query:

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
                                    .terms("users")
                                     .field("USER")
                                     .size(10)
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch(_index)
                .setSize(0)
                .addAggregation(aggregation)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

But when I try to convert it into a JSON object

```
JSONObject SRJSON = new JSONObject(res.toString());
```

It is saying

> Constructor JSONObject(String) undefined
>
> Remove argument to match JSONObject()

And I am using below maven plugin and elastic vs ~2.3:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that json-simple has **JSONObject(String source)** constructor and it's a compile time error. If you wish to follow the way it is being used in [link to other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190070/convert-elasticsearch-searchresponse-object-to-jsonobject), consider using the below dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

After including the dependency this snippet will work:

```
JSONObject SRJSON = new JSONObject(res.toString());
```

refer: [JSONObject(String source)](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great !! It solved my issue working like a charm now....Just curious to know...what are the other ways to do the same using other plugins ??